# git において、add と commit 、と push の違い

Tags: git

git において、`add(staging) と commit` と `push` の違いは何ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `git add` は次にコミットするファイルを準備する段階
- `git commit` は `git add` でステージングしたファイルの保存を確定する
- `git push` はローカルリポジトリの内容をリモートリポジトリに反映(同期)する

**参考:**

[Git Cheat Sheet: Commands and Best Practices | Rebel](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/git-cheat-sheet)

[image]

Comment: この図にリモート追跡ブランチを加えるとどうなりますか？できればこれ（リモート追跡ブランチ）を含めて俯瞰したいです。（質問の範囲と異なるかもしれませんが、質問する際分からなかったのはこの点です。）